# When using Vue.js on a GitHub page, I had the following problem

Tags: vue.js, github-pages

[Using {{message}} for github blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFTOS.png)

[{{message}} not showing on github blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BPIU.jpg)

[The result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG5Td.png)

From the feather github blog

```
<div id = "app"> {{message}}
</ div>
```

I am using Vus.js code {{}}.

Just like the first picture yet, when you enter the first picture blanks appear.

I want to get the result like the third picture.

Comment: Please do add some explanation to the question along with the images and use `!` before the markdown of images to see the magic.

Comment: Add your complete code in your component or the steps you have tried in github, that help better to solve your issue